# AdMob Publisher ID, MY_AD_UNIT_ID

Tags: android, admob

Both Publisher ID and MY_AD_UNIT_ID are same or they point to different things? I connected a app to admob but I don't know what is MY_AD_UNIT_ID. plz help me

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different.

PUBLISHER_ID looks like:  "pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
And can be found at the top of your Admob dashboard.

Your ad unit id looks like "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY".
Ie you ad unit id contains your publisher id.

You will have one ad unit id for each add unit.